# Возможно ли сделать видео-конференцию на сайте на canvas ? (несколько камер и чат)

Tags: javascript, canvas, потоки-данных, streaming, webrtc

Мне надо разработать видео-конференции на сайте, а точнее несколько камер + блок для картинок/слайдеров + рисование. Основная проблема не вывести несколько потоков сверху в отдельные canvas, а именно всю эту картинку сохранить в видео, чтобы в будущем можно было сохранить в mp4, а для этого надо уже 1 общий canvas делать.

Прям даже не знаю как быть, можно ли вообще подобное сделать? Другие делали подобное на Flash, как я понял.

Внешне выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Указали бы хоть адрес страницы - **[GoToMeeting](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoToMeeting)**

Comment: Подобных сайтов уйму. GoToMeeting использует flash, меня больше интересует на webrtc подобное.